# Access violation error when trying to free an array

Tags: c, windows

I'm currently working on structures for a personnal project. I'm trying to use dynamically-allocated bidimensionnal arrays, and then free the space they're taking. An error occurs when I try to free the allocated space.

I was able to narrow down the source of the issue down to the function I had set up to destroy my structures, but wasn't able to pinpoint the cause of the error within. More concerning is the fact that the error, an access violation, only triggers half of the time.
I've included the functions below, with a few comments. I'm sorry if I'm including too much code here, but I'm geniunely lost at words and do feel like the way I initialize the structures may have an impact on whether I'm destroying them correctly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct f_part f_part;
typedef struct field field;

//these are the structures I used:
//part of a field: includes a character and a color
struct f_part
{
    char caractere;
    short int color;
};


//field: points to a bidimensionnal array of f_part, and remember its size
struct field
{
    int fsize_x;
    int fsize_y;
    f_part **fbody;
};

field* fieldInitialize(const int size_x, const int size_y)  //this function seems to work correctly, I've mostly added it as an indicator
{
    field* terrain = malloc(sizeof(*terrain));
    if (terrain == NULL)
        printf("fail1");
    terrain->fsize_x = size_x;
    terrain->fsize_y = size_y;
    f_part* ptrToFPart = NULL;
    terrain->fbody = malloc(sizeof(ptrToFPart) * size_x);   //this is where I allocate the space for an array of pointers
    if (terrain->fbody == NULL)
        printf("fail2");

    int i,j;
    for (i = 0 ; i < size_x ; i++)
    {
        terrain->fbody[i] = malloc(sizeof(f_part) * size_y);
        for (j = 0 ; j < size_y ; j++)
        {
            terrain->fbody[i][j].caractere = 'a';
            terrain->fbody[i][j].color = 0;
        }
    }
    terrain->fsize_x = size_x;
    terrain->fsize_y = size_y;
    return terrain;
}



void fieldDestroy(field* terrain)   //this is the function that is supposed to destroy the object and free the memory, and fails
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0 ; i < terrain->fsize_x ; i++)
    {
        free(terrain->fbody[i]);    //this part always goes well
    }
    printf("flag 1\n");
    free(terrain->fbody);   //this is where the access violation happens, when it does
    printf("flag 2\n");
    free(terrain);      //this part goes well too
    printf("flag 3\n");
}

int main()
{
    field* testField = fieldInitialize(5, 5);
    fieldDestroy(testField);       //This is the function that fails. Sometimes.
return 0;
}
```

The error systematically happens on that second-to-last line, when I try to free the space allocated for the array of pointers. Except it doesn't always happen! Sometimes, I can free terrain->fbody, and everything goes well, but other times, I can't free the space.
The error I get is 0xC0000005, which apparently translates to "access violation". Which I understand would be common when dealing with dynamic memory allocation, but then why do I seem to get the error only half of the time?

Edit : Okay, so I've edited a bit of the code. Interestingly enough, while my Windows 10 would fail between flags 1 and 2, my Windows 7 fails between flags 2 and 3, and returns too a 0xC0000005 error. But again, only occasionally.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: What is the value of `size_x`? Are you sure the `malloc` of `terrain->fbody` always successful?

Comment: field* terrain = malloc(sizeof(terrain)); is incorrect. It should be field* terrain = malloc(sizeof(*terrain)); Actually I would prefer field* terrain = malloc(sizeof *terrain);

Comment: Most likely cause: You are writing outside the bounds of allocated memory, *somewhere* in your code. Run the application with [Application Verifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/application-verifier) to move closer towards the root cause.

Comment: @xing alright, I've edited the code a bit. (also, the a was supposed to be a defined preprocessor character, but I've edited it for the sake of clarity.)
this code still triggers an error, but uh. not on the same spot depending on the OS? is this normal?

Comment: @IInspectable yes, I know that. the error happens when I attempt to free previously allocated memory

Comment: @Yuanhui I always do in my actual program, I have just removed the security checks to make the code more compact of stackoverflow... should I have not done that?

Comment: @Yunnosch Is this better?

Comment: @Stuart wait, you can do that?

Comment: @xing I just did and somehow it works? Thanks, @Stuart!...how does that work? I mean, if you don't mind explaining

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very late to it. The question wasn't marked as resovled, but it *had* been resolved by Stuart in the comments of the question

> field* terrain = malloc(sizeof(terrain)); is incorrect. It should be field* terrain = malloc(sizeof(terrain)); Actually I would prefer field terrain = malloc(sizeof *terrain);

Indeed, you can write `yourStruct *ptr = malloc(sizeof(*yourStruct))` (size of "what's being pointed at by ptr).

Answer (score 0):

In C, you must precede structure names with `struct`.  So your functions should be declared:

```
struct field* fieldInitialize( ... )
```

and your allocations should be

```
struct field* terrain = malloc(sizeof(struct field));
```

You could also define these structures as types:

```
typedef struct
{
    int fsize_x;
    int fsize_y;
    struct f_part **fbody;
} field;
```